# High-School Level Probability

Tags: probability

If 3 points are taken on a circle, what is the probability that the triangle formed by joining these points is an obtuse angled triangle?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far?

Comment: Also, how are the points chosen? Independent and uniformly distributed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited.
Probability that they are on the same side of a diameter. If the points are a, b and c then by first choosing a , the probability that b and c are in the same side of the diagonal formed by a is (1/2)(1/2)= 1/4. Since a is chosen arbitrarily at first by symmetry this will be the case if we had chosen b or c first. Hence the probability is 3/4.

Comment: Could you explain how you get $1/4$? The answer to Manoj's linked duplicate question differs.

Comment: Because it's not really a duplicate.